# How to copy contents of a table of multiple SQLIte DBs to one new SQLIte DB

Tags: database, sqlite

I have several DBs having a table called tbl_server_NE_details;

The DBs are;
SERVER_1.db,
SERVER_2.db,
SERVER_3.db,
SERVER_4.db

Each of them have a table tbl_server_NE_details

I want to copy content of all tbl_server_NE_details to a new db;

SERVER_ALL.db

this should contain one table tbl_server_NE_details and it should have content from all the individual DBS.

Following command works for one table but not for all;

sqlite3 SERVER_1.db ".dump tbl_server_NE_details" | sqlite3 SERVER_ALL.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general**

Use attach database (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).
This allows you to easily move data from one database to another.

For example, to copy table a from database one.db to table b in database two.db you do:

```
sqlite3 one.db
```

then at the prompt:

```
attach database "two.db" as two;
create table two.b as select * from a;
```

This method does not copy the schema of the table. If you want to 
mirror the schema you have to do, after the attach:

```
create table two.b <rest of the statement>;
insert into two.b select * from a;
```

**The solution you need**

You can simply attach each of the different databases and insert their contents into the database/table that will contain all the tuples.
You can use "detach database" to disconnect each of the databases once
you don't need them any more (sqlite has a limit in the number of databases that can be attached simultaneously).

You can start by running the command you indicated in your question:

```
sqlite3 SERVER_1.db ".dump tbl_server_NE_details" | sqlite3 SERVER_ALL.db
```

The for each of the other databases do the following (replace SERVER_2.db
with the corresponding name: run sqlite3 SERVER_2.db, then:

```
attach database "SERVER_ALL.db" as all; 
insert into all.tbl_server_NE_details select * from tbl_server_NE_details;
```

You can easily script this operation.

Comment: Thanks this works. How do I run these series of commands from Java program ? I have tried running them by putting these in shell file and also directly using runtime exec function. But they don't seem to work.